# How to individually open files in a given directory?

Tags: bash

I have a BASH code where the code takes a CSV file as an argument, ie:

```
:~$ ./mycode.sh mycsv.csv
```

where the `mycsv.csv` gets processed by `mycode.sh`. There is a lot of CSV files in the directory and all of them need to be individually processed. How can I make the code go through each of the CSV files?

Comment: Improve your script to handle multiple input files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `for` construct to loop over the `.csv` files and pass one at a time to the script:

```
for file in *.csv; do ./mycode.sh "$file"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `find` command for this:-

```
 find . -name "*.csv" -type f  -printf '%f\n' -exec ./mycode.sh {} \;
```

- find files with extension `.csv` without the leading `./`
- Run the script `mycode.sh` for all the files returned from the current folder

**Update:-**

To handle file-names that  contain newlines or other types of white space or other special characters, am adopting `-print0` from `find` and reading them with a de-limiter `''`. Also using `bash` parameter-expansion, to strip leading characters `./` from find command

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -name "*.csv" -type f -print0 |
   while IFS= read -r -d '' x; do
       ./mycode.sh "${x:2}"
   done
```

Comment: Note that `-printf` is not standard. Since you only want to print the filename, use `-print` instead (it will print the leading directories too, though, but at least it's portable).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Thanks for the suggestion, check out my updated answer!

Comment: Well, `-print0` is non-standard too. Note that your original answer handles all types of funny symbols in filenames properly (spaces, newlines, globs, etc.), without the need of the `while` loop (and non-standard `-print0`). To achieve the same portably: `find . -name '*.csv' -type f -exec sh -c 'printf %s\\n "$0"; ./mycode.sh "${0#./}"' {} \;`, or any variations on the theme.